# add a description to an enumerated math equation in line

Tags: math-mode

How to add a description to an enumerated math equation in line? When I do this the sentence is printed without word spacing`\item$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{c}{x^n}=0, where c is any constant and n > 0$` and it prints like

[image]

How to make proper word spacing for sentence inserted?